# Html: What is the correct order of <a> and <p> tags?

Tags: html, anchor

***Which of the following, if either, is correct  by standards?***

```
<!-- Do the links surround the target link object -->
<a href=''><p>Link Description</p></a>
<!-- or does the object type encapsulate the link-->
<p><a href=''>Link Description</a></p>
```

I know they function the same, But it's a best practice/standards question. This could apply to ul/ol too.

The only reason I think to favor the `<a>` tag inside is with a situation like:

`<p>This is a longer sentence with a <a href=''>short link here</a></p>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The first example is only allowed in HTML5.

The second example is allowed in all versions of HTML/XHMTL.

Answer (score 21):

You can't wrap a block element with an inline element. You have to do this in that way:

`<p><a href=''>Link Description</a></p>`

This is W3C standard. Check [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)!

Comment: You can have block level links in HTML5: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/ I would encourage everyone to start adopting HTML5.

Comment: @edeverett Intuitively, I liked the idea of making a whole block a link, which is just what html5 allows. I'm new to web development, html5 has been at least partially supported ever since I started. So I have been able to do both methods with the same result, which is why I decided to ask which is preferred. Thanks for the help

Comment: For HTML5 both ways are good and can be used in different circumstances. If you want a whole block level element to be linked -or a bunch of block level elements - then just wrap them in an anchor tag. If you just want some inline content linked carry on using <a> like normal. This is one of the less high profile but most useful updates to the new spec.

Answer (score 7):

As of HTML 5, anchor tags (`<a></a>`) are allowed to wrap around almost anything, including paragraphs. So either example is valid, although I tend to prefer having anchors inside paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

anchors (a) should be inside a block element. So

```
<p><a>...</a></p>
```

Comment: Obsolete w.r.t. HTML5 and does not state HTML version.

Comment: Given the post was from 2011, I don't think HTML5 was an option.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the second one, than the `<p>` is not inheriting attributes of `<a>` and keeping it's original formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements such as `<a>` are often contained within block-level elements such as `<p>`. The block elements provide the structure needed to present your data.

Answer (score 0):

I always put the `<p>` tags inside unless the amount of text is large.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this now, here is a link that adds more context to the accepted answer.

> The first example is only allowed in HTML5.
>
> The second example is allowed in all versions of HTML/XHMTL.

[HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)