# how is the row's height in css defined in this case?

Tags: css, css-grid

Look at this first grid with just one direct child.

```css
div {
display:grid;
grid-template-column:120px;
width:120px;
margin:auto;
}
a {background-color:red;}
 img{
width:100%;
/* height:100%; */ uncomment to see the effect.
}
```

```html
<div/>
<a href="https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/qRZeGZ" >
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" >
<p >
<span class="code">&lt;</span>
Meh Meh Meh
<span class="code">/&gt;</span>
</p>
</a>

</div>
```

**Issue**

Now if I uncomment just that one line, the image takes the full height of the row, and the remaining element is kicked out:

```css
div {
display:grid;
grid-template-column:120px;
width:120px;
margin:auto;
}
a {background-color:red;}
 img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div/>
<a href="https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/qRZeGZ" >
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png" >
<p >
<span class="code">&lt;</span>
Meh Meh Meh
<span class="code">/&gt;</span>
</p>
</a>

</div>
```

**Hypothesis/Question**

Is it the height of the row calculated using something like `height:calc(aspectRatio*width)`  for the image, and in consequence independent of the height we define?

Or whats going on here?

Comment: what browser? ...

Comment: You don't see any rareness there? I'm on mozilla dev edition, the newest one. But I believe this is a general thing that images using height:100% and width:100% take the full with of the container, kicking out any other element inside...@TemaniAfif Any ideas?

Comment: I've also made a codepen if you want to check it better https://codepen.io/misterybodon/pen/QWyXprd

Comment: there is no difference in Chrome, only Firefix is giving different results

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem:

**There shouldn't be a paragraph inside an anchor tag**. Removing the par and using a span fix the issue.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101711/html-what-is-the-correct-order-of-a-and-p-tags)